# Accessing JSON objects in this format

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

```
const login = await Signupdetails.find(req.body); 
login =
    [
      {
        PersonalInformation: {
          firstName: 'aravind',
          lastName: 'john',
          phoneNumber: 9736363777,
          DOB: 1999-07-08T18:30:00.000Z
        },
        Address: {
          street: 'pillai',
          city: 'Chennai',
          pincode: 89997,
          state: 'kerala',
          country: 'India'
        },
        password: 'social',
        _id: 607804f65c166c32144ae227,
        email: 'hari@gmail.com',
        userName: 'hari',
        __v: 0
      }
    ]
```

If I try using login.userName ,its showing undefined . This is a part of my Get API request . I used node.js and mongodb

Comment: Thats because you dont have an Object, you have a list of objects with length 1

Comment: login is an array: `login[0].userName`

Answer (score 0):

You have a list, if you want login to be an Object, remove '[' characters:

```
login =
      {
        PersonalInformation: {
          firstName: 'aravind',
          lastName: 'john',
          phoneNumber: 9736363777,
          DOB: 1999-07-08T18:30:00.000Z
        },
        Address: {
          street: 'pillai',
          city: 'Chennai',
          pincode: 89997,
          state: 'kerala',
          country: 'India'
        },
        password: 'social',
        _id: 607804f65c166c32144ae227,
        email: 'hari@gmail.com',
        userName: 'hari',
        __v: 0
      }
```

On the other hand, if you want login to be a list, you have to access:

```
login[0].userName
```